# How to show one viewcontroller over other as overlay in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controller which Controller `A` and `B`. `A` controller displaying some info on screen. On top right of `A` screen I have a `UIButton` on click of button I want to show a help screen which will have some labels & when I touch the help screen it should go away.

I can do it by adding a view on top of all view & hide, show it. But I want to know how can I show `HelpScreenViewController` as a semitransparent view controller on top of first view controller on click of `UIButton`. When I tap on `HelpScreenViewController` it should go away.

**EDIT:**
I have added below code but does not work

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TopOverVc"];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a story. What is your question? What code do you have? As explained in the guides, [don't just copy in your entire program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: check updated question

Answer (score 0):

For what you described, you dont need a ViewController to contain the 'TopOver' view.  A normal UIView would be better.  Place that within your first ViewController, in interface builder.  Drag it into your A ViewController class, along with the button.  When the button is clicked, just show/hide your view containing the info you need.

Comment: I know but in that case my code become lengthy in one file.Just to avoid that i am using another view controller so that i can write helpscreen code in otehr file

Comment: You can still put your code in a separate file - put it in your UIView subclass.  Add your UIView to the UIViewController in IB.  Then create a new file, a subclass of UIView - call it HelpView or something like that.  Then in IB, find your UIView and change its class to HelpView.  Now you can put all your code in your new class, and it doesnt have to go in the UIViewController.

Comment: @LukeSmith I like your idea but how to dismiss a view when I scroll down on the view? Is there any method provided by apple similar to 'dismissviewcontroller' which is only applicable for view controllers but I want to obtain similar fuinctionailty for my UIView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the containerView control and you can add the childViewController for it. You can use this as overlay by doing the background colors transparent as your needs.

This article may help help you http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/21/ios-container-views/

One more thing, you can set this containerview hide/visible as you need.